# C# regex search and replace all integer numbers surrounded by space

Tags: c#, regex

I apologize if this is a duplicated question.  I haven't found a solution for my situation.

I would like to search for all integer numbers surrounded by space, and replace them with a space.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" 123 123 456 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123");
StringBuilder sbDigits = new StringBuilder(Regex.Replace(sb.ToString()), @"\s[0-9]+\s", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

`sbDigits` return value is, "123 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 123"

I would like the return value to be "fdsa jkl xyz x5x"

So, what is going on?  How do I ensure that I am getting the duplicate number?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate strings" then? It sounds like you just want to get rid of numbers.

Comment: And I'm sure this code doesn't even compile..

Comment: You guys are funny.  I appreciate the comments...  This code is from an example console program I have to get this piece working for a bigger project.  It does compile, unless I missed a semicolon.  What I mean by "duplicate strings" is any concurrent duplicate such as jkl jkl or 123 123.  Either starting string will not pick up the next meaning, jkl jkl will be jkl and 123 123 will be 123.

Comment: @Mike: you said you would like to search for all integer numbers surrounded by space, and replace them with a space. Your issue here isn't caused by duplicates, you should edit that part out of your title so that people looking for the same thing you are can easily find the question.

Comment: Thank you @Robin, I will revise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Test string:

```
 123 123 456 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123 5x
```

Regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)[\d]+(?=\s|$)
```

Working example:

http://regex101.com/r/tJ5rA6

C#:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" 123 123 456 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123 5x");
StringBuilder sbDigits = new StringBuilder(Regex.Replace(sb.ToString()), @"(?<=\s|^)[\d]+(?=\s|$)", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Return value:

```
fdsa jkl xyz x5x 5x
```

Comment: `[ ]` is redundant: `\d` is the shortcut for `[0-9]` and enough here.

Comment: This won't capture/replace the whitespace around the numbers due to the use of lookahead/lookbehind.  Depending on what others needs are.  (Did not know you could 'or' `^`/`$`, interesting!)

Answer (score 0):

```
String fixed = Regex.Replace(originalString, "\\s*\\d+\\s+", "");
```

Comment: Is the double `\\` necessary? Also, this won't get the last one since there's no white space after it.

Comment: I believe the double '\\' is necessary when not using the "@" literal symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:  [image: Regular expression visualization]

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" 123 123 456 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123");
StringBuilder sbDigits = new StringBuilder(Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(), @"\s*[0-9]+\d\s*", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled));
```

[Regex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zBLnW3PshRqMq807)

Comment: This one replaces all digits.  I'm looking to replace only words that are digits:
" 123 " is ok
" 5x5 ", " x5x ", " 5x ", " x5 " NOT ok

Comment: @kmatyaszek: `[0-9]+\d` is the same thing as `\d{2,}`. `\d+` would suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
search:  @"( [0-9]+)(?=\1\b)"
replace: ""
```

Comment: This didn't work either.  I'm looking to replace whole words of digits not all digits.

Comment: @Mike: this works well, If you are unable to make a simple test, don't post a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you add in word-breaks (`\b`) you can capture only 'digit words' (which is what it sounds like you want.  And you can capture zero or more white space around the digits while not matching the numbers inside letters:

```
\s*\b\d+\b\s*
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about Regex. But it can be done with a little `LINQ`:

```
var str = "123 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 123";
var parts = str.Split().Where(x => !x.All(char.IsDigit));
var result = string.Join(" ", parts); //  fdsa jkl xyz x5x
```

Answer (score 0):

## What hapenned

Look what happens when you apply your regex, which matches a whitespace, any number of digits, and another whitespace:

```
"( 123 )123 456 789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123"
// regex engine matches " 123 ", first fitting pattern
"( 123 )123( 456 )789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x 456 456 123 123"
// regex engine matches " 456 ", because the first match "ate" the whitespace
"( 123 )123( 456 )789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x( 456 )456 123 123"
// matches the first " 456 "
"( 123 )123( 456 )789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x( 456 )456( 123 )123"
// matches " 123 "
"( 123 )123( 456 )789 fdsa jkl xyz x5x( 456 )456( 123 )123"
```

So the regex only found `" 123 "`, `" 456 "`, `" 456 "` and  `" 123 "`. You replaced these matches with a whitespace and this is what caused your output.

## What you want to do

You want to match word boundaries with something that won't "eat" the word boundary (here, the whitespace). As suggested by many others,

```
\b\d+\b
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This one does also work.  I don't recall others besides you giving this answer.  Had I seen this before @MElliott I would've accepted this.

Comment: Your question was a little bit unclear as the duplicate thing threw a few people of. Try to make the title clearer, then mark the answer you think fits the question the best as accepted (you can un-tick if necessary), so that for future reference everything will be as easy to find as possible.

Comment: You got this right.  I apologize if others interpreted, "search for all integer numbers surrounded by space" to mean anything other than " 9999 ".